# Mentioning of the CoC in the final FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, faq-suggestion

Please add to the FAQ a link to our Code of Conduct and the Leadership Code of conduct:

Under the title "Be nice" it can be added:

Please follow the [Ubuntu Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct) and [Ubuntu Leadership Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/leadership-conduct) when participating in this community.

Answer (score 7):

I think it should. The tone here has already been professional and courteous, so it's probably best to list it while the going is good.

In addition we have the [Leadership Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/leadership-conduct); do we think this is something we should ask moderators to look at? I am unsure if the forums moderators are held to it.

Comment: I don't have a problem following the LCoC, and think both of them would make good FAQ additions.

Comment: I'm not convinced the Leadership Code of Conduct is relevant to Stack Exchange.